# Is there a quick way to attach an eventhandler on Enter or ESC keypressed with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, event-handling, keyboard-events

I want to add event-handlers to my textbox input element for Enter and Escape keypressed.

Is there a quick way to attach an event-handler on Enter or ESC keypressed with jQuery?

Comment: You do realise that pressing ENTER on a form textbox submits the form?

Comment: No, it will call a webservice.

Comment: Nevertheless when a user will press the ENTER and if that is within a FORM (that you override its default submit with an Ajax request) it will fire `submit` event (whether that be normal or Ajax request if it's overridden). But if you're not using FORM then you don't have to worry about this.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: I'm not so sure that this is a duplicate of the referenced question. Because AFAIK he's asking about the **quickest way to attack keyboard events** to inputs and not **how to attach them to work** (hence I'm voting for reopening the question).

Comment: @Robert: On second look, I agree with you.  Thanks for the second opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do what you need:

```
        $("$#textboxName").keyup(function(event)
        {
            if(event.keyCode == 13) 
            {
                //Enter keypress event.
            }
            if(event.keyCode == 27)
            {
                //Escape keypress event.
            }
        });
```

or if you want to hit either event, you would just need an or:

```
       $("$#textboxName").keyup(function(event)
            {
                if(event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 27) 
                {
                    //Enter or Escape keypress event.
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

### The page-by-page reusable way with a jQuery plugin

To make things a bit more generic and reusable across pages, you could write a jQuery plugin called `handleKey` (code not final and may contain bugs):

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        handleKey: function(keyCode, handler) {
            if ($.isFunction(handler))
            {
                this.keyup((function(k, h){
                    return function(evt){
                        if (evt.keyCode == k)
                        {
                            h(evt);
                        }
                    };
                }
                })(keyCode, handler));
            }
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This can be even further customized to accept a string for `keyCode` that would be a comma separated string to handle multiple keys with the same handler.

Usage would be:

```
$("input#Username").handleKey(13, function(evt){
    // your functionality
});
```

I'd put the plugin in my custom plugins javascript file and add reference to those pages that need it. Voila.